# ERROR RollupError: Could not resolve "./utils" from "./utils?commonjs-external"

Tags: rollupjs, nuxt3

I'm developing a large Nuxt3 project and suddenly I'm getting a rollupError I can not fix.
Here it is :

ERROR  RollupError: Could not resolve "./utils" from "./utils?commonjs-external"

Problem is nothing changed in that utils directory. My package.json file did not change. What I did was installing a new nuxt-calendly package that I then removed. This has maybe broke something in my app.

How would you investigate on such an issue ?

Thanks
Alex